# How can I read a column type & change it to a date it to sort by earliest date please?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL Workbench Commercial Editions 8.0 through 8.0.17

Would anyone know the proper syntax/command to:

1. check the type of column
2. change the type of column
3. recommend useful tutorial so that I can find that on my own
4. Recommend an alternative FREE & more beginner friendly tool than
   MySQL  Workbench please
5. I am trying to change the type of the column `install_date` into a
   date type so that it can accurately sort the earliest date.

Here is the command I typed:

```
ALTER TABLE PocketGemsSchema.pocketgemstable2 ALTER COLUMN Install_date year
```

Here is the error message:

> ALTER TABLE 'PocketGemsSchema.pocketgemstable2' ALTER COLUMN
>   'Install_date' year   Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near ''PocketGemsSchema.pocketgemstable2'
>   ALTER COLUMN 'Install_date' year' at line 1   0.00026 sec

Comment: The error message shows single-quotes in the query, but the query you're showing does not.  Are you sure that's the exact query you're executing?

Comment: You don't need to change the type of a column to use it for sorting.  Just use `order by install_date asc` for an ascending sort.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ,
That would be innacurate because sorting is different for a comlumn of type TEXT vs. a the same column of type year for e.g.

You can tet it yourself

Comment: @David
Yes that's the exact query.  Regardless, please let me know if you can answer any of my 3 questions please

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL Workbench, you can check the column types of a table by right clicking the table in the navigator and selecting "Table Inspector"

You can also query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view as follows

`SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'YourColumn' AND TABLE_NAME = 'YourTable';`

Try the following syntax to alter the column type

`ALTER TABLE PocketGemsSchema.pocketgemstable2 MODIFY Install_date year;`

An often cited alternative to Workbench is PHPMyAdmin, however my opinion is that Workbench is the best tool for MySQL

Comment: Thanks, 
 https://youtu.be/gHmI2EvLXYU

 error :
----
 SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'Install_date' AND TABLE_NAME = 'PocketGemsSchema.pocketgemstable2'  ALTER TABLE PocketGemsSchema.pocketgemstable2 MODIFY Install_date year Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE PocketGemsSchema.pocketgemstable2 MODIFY Install_date year' at line 3 0.00031 sec

Can you help please?

Comment: What happens if you take the where clause off?

Comment: Could you please type the command you want me to try? I am not sure I understand please. Moreover, would you recommend useful tutorial so that I can answer that on my own please?-- My google searches were vain

Comment: I've just edited the code and added a semi colon to the end. That might be the problem

Comment: It didin't work unfortunately. here is the error: 11:39:16 SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'Install_date' AND TABLE_NAME = 'PocketGemsSchema.pocketgemstable2'   ALTER TABLE PocketGemsSchema.pocketgemstable2 MODIFY Install_date year Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE PocketGemsSchema.pocketgemstable2 MODIFY Install_date year' at line 4 0.0030 sec

Comment: Looks like you have run two queries at once without terminating either of them with the semi colon which I added to my answer

Comment: That wasn't the problem. Workbench 8.0 seems to run commands with or without ";"

Comment: I was able to get this command to work: ALTER TABLE pocketgemstable2 modify Install_date char(15)

The issue now is that Install_date contains dates originally written in Text type -- e.g. 5-Nov-17 -- And whenever I run this command below, I get this error that I am now investigating.  Please let me know if you know how to effortlessly convert a text column written in format 5-Nov-17 into a date.

ALTER TABLE pocketgemstable2 modify Install_date date


Error Msg: 20:12:31 Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value: '5-Nov-17' for column 'Install_date' at row 1 0.023 sec